# how to get 10 lines below from a line in text file in c#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, text-files

I am reading a huge text file as shown below.What now wants is if i reach a particular word say `test:` here ,i will push values in to database from that line and out of which one value comes by concatenating values from 10 succeeding line.So  i want to get 10 succeeding lines and store it in to memory by using `File. Readalllines` or any other mechanism.How would i achieve it.As of now i am loading entire text file in to `File.Readalllines` which makes application very slow.

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
{
    string s = String.Empty;
    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (s.Contains("test:"))
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
i was studying spender answer,here one twist is suppose i have 10000 lines begins with `test:` and each line has `ID` and i am inserting lines based one ID like if ID==ID stored in dictionary ,then i have to store succeeding 10 lines not the very first 10 lines always,so how to do it?

**EDIT**
@spender i did it like `SkipWhile(line => (!line.Contains("ADD GTRX:") && !line.Contains(dict.CellId.ToString()))).Take(10);` but no luck at all

**EDIT**
@spender Finally i did it i have to move the brackets so full code what i did as shown below, i removed blank lines also

```
var linesOfInterest = File.ReadLines(filename)
                                                              .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("test:")).SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains(dictId.ToString())).Take(10);
                                    var output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, linesOfInterest).Trim().Split(';').Where(arg => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arg)).ToArray();
```

You are great ,have a nice day

Comment: for(int i=0;i<10;i++) liststring.Add(sr.ReadLine()); ?

Comment: @user5507337 i edited my question

Comment: hi, my idea is the same, whats the problem with the for?

Comment: The edit doesn't change anything. You *still* have to call ReadLine 10 times. Lines do not have a fixed length so you can't write code that reads, eg 10 lines. `ReadLine` actually reads all characters until it encounters the first newline

Comment: a list of strings :) List<string> liststring;

Comment: @peter you should really do some reading / research on some of the basic objects and types that are available to you start reading some C# basics tutorial online this will serve as a great reference in your future coding career..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is your friend here. It gives you an `IEnumerable<string>` that lazily hands back lines from a text file (i.e. the file is never fully loaded into memory). From there you can LINQ it up nicely.

```
var linesOfInterest = File.ReadLines(filePath)
                          .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains(searchTerm))
                          .Take(10);
var output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, linesOfInterest);
```

Comment: This does exactly what you want. What it is to test?

Comment: nice, but if file is huge as Peter says out of memory is behind the corner. Just seen the edit, I read File.ReadAllLines :)

Comment: @user5507337 - why do you think that?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera I agree.. what the issue is , is that the OP does not understand basics so I doubt he will be able to understand this awesome answer +1 spender

Comment: @MethodMan well, that's not really relevant. This is an excellent answer because it does the job, and does it in a clear, concise and performant way. There is plenty to learn from such a small piece of code.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera I think you are missing my point.. basically what I was stating is , how can someone learn a more complex approach without understanding the basics anyway.. Cheers.. it's Friday.. time to CHILL

Comment: @MethodMan I get your point, but it's still irrelevant. Let's hope the OP will accept the challenge of learning what's been answered. It's cool, man.

Comment: It's relevant from the standpoint that there are too many individuals that just come here as a `1 stop  shop` with hopes of someone providing them a quick solution without even trying something on there own or doing some simple googling to find already coded examples.. and yeah it's all good man.. Cheers..

Comment: @spender i modified my question

Comment: @spender i did it like SkipWhile(line => (!line.Contains("ADD GTRX:") && !line.Contains(dict.CellId.ToString()))).Take(10); but no luck at all

Comment: @spender finally i did and modified my question, you are great